# Anyone to show me how to target the div id="credit" when we perform on a click on a href class="toggle"

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p><a href="#credits" class="toggle btn btn-primary"><?php print $title; ?></a></p>

        <div id="credits1" class="wysiwyg hidden">
           Content - content
        </div>

</div>
```

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p><a href="#credits" class="toggle btn btn-primary"><?php print $title; ?></a></p>

        <div id="credits2" class="wysiwyg hidden">
           Content - content
        </div>

</div>

    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p><a href="#creditsn" class="toggle btn btn-primary"><?php print $title; ?></a></p>

        <div id="credits" class="wysiwyg hidden">
           Content - content
        </div>

</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by "target". Are you attempting to toggle the visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `href` attribute of the clicked element as the selector:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    // do something with the $target div here...
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cagce45f/)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that is a list so I have the <div class=row> repeating.

Comment: Then it works for the first element, can I use something like next() or closest etc ...So I will target always the div after my <a href>

Comment: You don't need that - it reads the `href` property of the `a` element to find the related `div` by its `id`.

Comment: @Mamadou I added a working example to the answer for you

Comment: I forgot to use different ids for my div ( credit). Thank you for putting me in the way of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get exactly what you wanted, but with this you can detect the click on the href and proccess some information on the "credit" div

```
$(".toggle").bind('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var credits = $('#credits');
    /* Do you thing */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to do with the div#credits, but there is a [working example](https://jsbin.com/hanopapipe/edit?html,js,output)

```
$("a.toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("div#credits").toggle();
})
```